# how do i make an error message pop up if the user inputed a string instead of a int

Tags: c#

i wanna make it so if the user didn't input a number an error message would pop up and restart a program, how can I do this?

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num1;
        int num2 = 0;
        bool is_var_int = false;

        Console.Write("enter a number:");
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("enter a number:");
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static int Count(int num_1, int num_2)
    {
        int output = num_1 + num_2;

        return output;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: [`Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8) will throw an exception on bad input. You can catch that exception. Or use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: There are 3 parts to your question: 1. catching the error, 2. showing a message, 3. restarting the app. Which one are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use int.TryParse. No need to restart the app if input errors are properly handled ;-)

```
void Main()
{
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(num1);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(num1);

        Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", Count(num1, num2));

}
```